# change enum values in button click codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

How do I change/update enum data type values in a button click using codeigniter

```
<?php
  foreach($req as $row):
?>
  <div class="col1">
      <?=$row->Offer?>
   </div>
   <div class=""col2>
      <button >Accept</a>
      <button >Decline</a>  
   </div>
 <?php endforeach ?>
```

I have enum values of:

> Accepted
>
> Declined
>
> Pending

and "Pending" as a default value.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this 

  <?php
       if($req->$row==0){
        ?>
        <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" title="Pending" href="<?php echo base_url();?>your_controller/UpdateOfferStatus/1&<?php echo $req->id; ?>">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
       </a>
       <?php
     }

     ?>
   <?php else if($req->$row==1) {

    <a class="btn btn-orange btn-xs" title="Accepted" href="<?php echo base_url();?>your_controller/UpdateOfferStatus/1&<?php echo $req->id; ?>">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
   </a>

   <?php
 }

 else{
  ?>

  <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="Declined" href="<?php echo base_url();?>your_controller/UpdateOfferStatus/2&<?php echo $req->id; ?>">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
 </a>
 <?php
}

?>
```